# f.label で表示されるテキスト文字列を取得したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails の勉強中で
[Signin Template for Bootstrap · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.jp/docs/4.3/examples/sign-in/)
のようなログイン画面をつけようと思ってます

`f.label :email`
と同じ文字列を次の行の input の placeholder に設定したいですが
i18n-railes ？が適当に日本語化してくれてるので
そのローカライズされた文字列を取得する方法ってありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「適当に日本語化してくれてる」というのがよく分からないのですが・・おそらく`config/locales`の配下に翻訳用ymlファイルを置いているですよね？？

であれば、`I18n.t` メソッドで取得できます。
例えば、`config/locales/ja.yml`というファイルがあったとして、その中身が次のような感じだとすると

```
ja:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: メールアドレス
...
```

次のようにすれば"メールアドレス"という文字列を取得できます。

```rb
I18n.t('activerecord.attributes.user.email')
```

（なおviewの中であれば、`I18n`は省略可能です）

## 参考

- https://railsguides.jp/i18n.html
- https://qiita.com/yutackall/items/0ff97132f31e5bacbf00

Comment: やっぱりそうするしかないんですね。f.label の返り値から取得できれば view のディレクトリ構成やビューの内容を移動したときにも対応しやすいかなと思ったんですが…　ありがとうございました！

Comment: 通常、f.labelで取得する翻訳は上記回答内の例のように'activerecord.attributes.モデル名.カラム名'になりますので、「viewのディレクトリ構成やビューの内容」には依存しません。I18nについて、Railsガイド（https://railsguides.jp/i18n.html）を一度読んでおいたほうがいいと思いますよ！